# Remove Pi (Pinyin)

Tags: 14.04, language-support, chinese, pinyin

Ubuntu 14.04. 
I installed SunPinyin and it worked good. But under language bar, there are three choices: Eng, Pi (Pinyin), Sunpinyin. I wanted to remove Pi (Pinyin)(which does not work). 
Tried remove, purge ibus pinyin command and Pi (Pinyin) is still there. 
Text entry only showed two choices: English and Chinese (SunPinyin). Help!

Answer (score 2):

You can try finding out what other pinyin libraries are installed using:

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep pinyin
ibus-sunpinyin                  install
libpinyin4:amd64                deinstall
libsunpinyin3:amd64             install
sunpinyin-data                  install
```

and then remove it using `apt-get remove` or `aptitude remove`

`$ sudo apt-get remove ibus-libpinyin`

Answer (score 2):

I had the issue too and this solved by following Shiheng Zhang instruction.
Just to extend what he suggested.

Reinstall ibus-pinyin

```
sudo apt-get install ibus-pinyin
ibus restart
```

Then, right click on the language icon and choose 'Text entry settings...'
Then, remove 'Chinese (Pinyin)' from the input source and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to remove Pi too but failed. I reinstalled ibus-pinyin and deselected Chinese(pinyin), that Pi disappeared.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Answer (score 0):

Some times, the problem is that the `IBus` daemon is not running, so when you open the  'Text entry settings...' dialog, you don't see the "Chinese(pinyin)" entry there. What I do is follow this method by first start the ibus daemon:

https://askubuntu.com/a/422411/383308

Which just start the ibus daemon, after that, you can see the "Chinese(pinyin)" entry is shown in the dialog(suppose you have ibus-pinyin already installed), now, you can click the "-" key to remove this entry.

After that, you can stop the ibus daemon(kill the process), and this time, the "Pi" icon is disappeared.

Hope that helps.