# Unable to type in a terminal, but there is a prompt

Tags: command-line, 18.04, keyboard, ubuntu-mate

*I am running Ubuntu-MATE 18.04.4 LTS, and using MATE Terminal 1.20.0.*

**All of my existing terminal sessions are unresponsive to most keyboard input.**  Basically, I cannot type anything meaningful into them.  For all other applications, my keyboard is working fine.

There are five keys on the keyboard that are working normally: `/`, `*`, `-`, `+`, and `Enter` -- but only from the numeric keypad (`NumLock` has no effect either).

I am able to paste commands into the terminals using either the middle mouse button or the menus.  I tried running `reset` in an effected terminal, but this did not fix anything.  There is also a `Reset and Clear` option in the terminal menu, but this simply hides the prompt and I can find no way to recover it.  `ctrl-C` has no effect either.

When I open a new terminal with `ctrl-alt-T`, the new terminal suffers from the same defect.  However, if I open a new terminal from the Mate menu, it works fine.

I plugged in a different keyboard (wired-USB) and the effect was the same when using the second keyboard.

The *easy* fix is to kill my existing terminal sessions and start fresh.  I would prefer not to do that since I have many open terminal windows and tabs and I don't want to lose my state.  Also, if there is a systemic problem, I would like to know how to deal with this in the future.

A few times in recent weeks, I have experienced similar problems with other applications (maybe Chromium-browser), so this may be related.

***Is there a command or magic key sequence that might allow me to resume my existing terminal sessions?***

Comment: If you have not set customs profiles for your MATE terminal you can reset its settings with `dconf reset -f /org/mate/terminal/` and retry.

Comment: Maybe try `stty echo`?  If you have `stty -echo` set, nothing will show as you type.  But the trick here is, you can still type, and it will still use the command you typed, you just won't be able to see it.

Comment: No effect (on this problem) from the suggestions in the prior two comments.  However, my desktop went seriously haywire when I accidentally ran `dconf reset -f /org/mate/` -- **I don't recommend it** (it reset all of my desktop customizations, including panels and workspaces).

Comment: The potential "culprit" that I was trying to remember is [ibus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ibus), which came to my attention by showing up in the panel after I rebooted.

Comment: The previously mentioned command *that I accidentally ran*, actually reset every custom setting in every MATE application.  It was like starting from a clean install of Ubuntu.

Comment: Oooh -- It even reset my "mate tweak tool" settings (Window manager), which I finally realized is why my desktop has been buggy (sadly, it works best with "No compositor").

Answer (score 3):

Something tells me that it was [ibus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ibus) that needed a kick...

- [iBus doesn't seem to restart](https://askubuntu.com/q/389903/11522)

Comment: Today I resolved my keyboard-in-terminal problem using "Quit" from the IBus panel icon (Looks like "EN", for English on mine).  Maybe I could have just used "Restart".

Comment: Today I resolved a dead-keyboard for one browser instance using "Restart" from the IBus panel icon.

Comment: It's amazing how many random quirks can be fixed in Ubuntu by knowing how to restart the underlying service (or application).

Comment: `IBus notification -> Restart`.  Once again, this solution has saved me from a disruptive application restart.

Comment: I just had exactly the same situation, but in terminator terminals. I've opened a MATE terminal and executed `ibus restart` and it unlocked the terminator ones. This saves my day :D